# Working with date picker: seemingly simple task

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

Below is a fiddle example as a starting point:
http://jsfiddle.net/1ezos4ho/8/

Essentially I would want the followings to happen:

1. The date selected to be dynamically be added as the value of the input, where it would be like `<input type text value="date selected"....`

Update:

```
<script> 
$(function() { // on load function, everything inside here will not run until the pagehas had time to load 
      $("#dpick").datepicker(); //date picker added here at its state its only able to grab the startDate not the end date not sure why

$('.filter').click(function(){ 

                document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "<div class='loading-indication'><img src='ajax-loader.gif' /> &nbsp; Please wait... Loading New Courses...</div>";

var datastring = $('#testform').serialize(); // this will create key/value pairs to send to the phph page like `duration5=5` with a `&` separating each key/value pair 
$('#display-datastring').html(datastring); // this line is just so you can see the variable being created 
$.ajax({ 
url: 'fetch_pages.php', 
type: 'post', 
data: datastring, 
success: function(res){ 

$('#results').html(res); 
} 
}); 


}); 

}); 
</script>
```

Below is the form:

```
 <form id="testform"> 

            <input type="text"  placeholder="Start" style="width: 40%;" name="dateStart" class="filter" id="dpick" > 
                            <label id="Paylbl0">To</label>

             <input type="text"  style="width: 40%;" placeholder="End" name="dateEnd" class="filter" id="dpick">
```

problem is function start to run as soon as i hit the input when it should only be executed oncce the date has been selected. For some reason the date picker only comes in action with start date and not end date.

Comment: Can you explain a little better what it's doing that you don't want?

Comment: its not pasting the value within the value input, because i also want to grab its value and use it for something else. in particular i have search with optional filters such as date so i need to know the value of the start and end date

Comment: What POST output do you get when you submit your form?

Comment: I guess it will be easier if i tell you the end result it should be $startDate = isset($_POST['startDate']) ? $_POST['startDate']: null; 
$finishDate = isset($_POST['endDate']) ? $_POST['endDate']: null; where the post value would derive from the value of the input

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you fully understand how the plug-in works. It'll assign the value. Here's a quick "alert" test I did to show you. Just select a date. It watches for a change to the input and then alerts the date selected - based on the **VALUE**.

Submit your form (or grab the input value via js, as per my example) and it should work.

http://jsfiddle.net/1ezos4ho/11/

A js example to show you...

```
var i = 3;

$(function() {
    $(".dpick").datepicker();

    $('.dpick').on('change', function() {
        $val = $(this).val();
        alert($val);
    });
});
```

Also, make sure you name your inputs if you're submitting them via a form. based on your comment, you're doing a POST request which is looking for those items which haven't been identified.

In short, `$_POST['endDate']` is looking for an `input` with the name, endDate.

`<input type="text" name="startDate" placeholder="Start" style="width: 40%;" class="dpick" id="dpick0" >`

`<input type="text"  name="endDate" style="width: 40%;" placeholder="End" class="dpick" id="dpick1">`

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. the end result it should be $startDate = isset($_POST['startDate']) ? $_POST['startDate']: null; $finishDate = isset($_POST['endDate']) ? $_POST['endDate']: null;  so in that page and within the javascript i somehow have to create a link between that function and this so that on another page (the php page) I am able to grab the post values

Comment: None of your inputs are named...? So the post request is returning NULL. Check updated answer.

Comment: thank you, i guess the other thing is that those lines are found at $startDate = isset($_POST['startDate']) ? $_POST['startDate']: null; $finishDate = isset($_POST['endDate']) ? $_POST['endDate']: null; fetch_pages.php and the date picker is in another page, how using ajax (dynamically) i can post it so that I am able to retrieve it at that page

Comment: Zero idea what you're talking about. No idea what fetch_pages.php is. How are you submitting the form now? Ajax? Update your answer with all your code. Because your question as it stands now, has nothing to do with you problem.